# Non-existent tris

Tags: modeling

I'm working on this mesh trying to reduce the number of tris I have. The mesh itself has around 9,000 tris, but when I go into object mode, it tells me I have 23,000 tris. I can't seem to locate the source of the extra 12,000 tris.

Anybody have any solutions?

In edit mode
[image]

In object mode
[image]

Comment: In object mode, the number of faces/tri's, etc.. includes any that are created as the result of modifiers (applied or not). So it basically shows you how many tri's you'd have if you applied all your modifiers. It also shows the total count for all objects in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

The extra geometry is likely the result of modifiers you are using (for example mirror, subdiv, etc). Pressing alt-h can reveal any hidden objects in the scene you haven't gotten rid of, if you want to be extra sure.